# How to read the first N lines, then read bytes?

Tags: rust

I have the following method in Rust:

```rust
   pub fn parse<B: BufRead>(buf: B) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
        let mut lines = buf.lines();

        // do stuff with lines

        let mut body_buf = vec![0; content_length];
        buf.read_exact(&mut body_buf[..]);

        // do stuff with body_buf
    }
```

But it's not working because `buf.lines()` consumes `self`. Is there a way to get a line-by-line iterator that does not consume `self`?

Comment: tl;dr: Try `buf.by_ref().lines()`.